# How to import dbtable data to data table in UFT

Tags: database, qtp, hp-uft

I inserted database checkpoint. Now, in OR, I see dbtable under test objects and dbtable object under checkpoint. When I click the dbtable object under checkpoint, I see the table with data.

This is the code was inserted

```
DbTable("DbTable").Check CheckPoint("DbTable")
```

When I run my script, I would like all the data from dbtable import to UFT Data Table. That means every time I run my script, it gets the updated records import into data table. How can I do it?